How do I access list values in flow
I am struggling a bit with accessing individual values in list that is returned by APEX code into the flow.
public class DynamicField {
    @InvocableVariable
    public String key;

    @InvocableVariable
    public String value;

    public DynamicField(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

I return List<List> and I am able to loop through and print each list. The keys and values are there and I am able to show them in form:
{
  "key": "value"
}

But in the flow, I would like to assign the value to a specific variable. And so far I am able to assign only the list, not the value.
Any idea how to do it?
Thanks.

To access individual values from the List in your Flow:
Loop through the List: Add a Loop element to iterate through the outer list of DynamicField objects.
Use Decision inside the Loop: Check the key using a Decision element to find the specific field you're looking for (like "email" or "phone").
Assign the Value: Once the key matches, use an Assignment element to store the corresponding value into a Flow variable.
This lets you extract specific values from your list and use them in the Flow. Simple as that!

I already tried that but cant access the keys. https://ibb.co/vkMkVKR
